# Sum the Values of Nested Custom Objects in Swift

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I am trying to add up the values found within some custom objects in Swift. I have the follow code working in a Playground:

```
//Custom Object
class EntryPack: NSObject{
  var date: String!
  var duration: Double!
  var customValues:[CustomValuePack] = [] //Nested array of objects declared below
}

//Another object to nest in the above
class CustomValuePack: NSObject{
  var name:String!
  var value: Double!
}

//Instantiate nested objects
let cv1 = CustomValuePack()
  cv1.name = "Day"
  cv1.value = 1.2
let cv2 = CustomValuePack()
  cv2.name = "Day"
  cv2.value = 1.3
let cv3 = CustomValuePack()
  cv2.name = "Night"
  cv2.value = 2.2

//Instantiate parent objects
let entry1 = EntryPack()
  entry1.date = "bingo"
  entry1.duration = 1.1

  entry1.customValues = [cv1, cv2]

let entry2 = EntryPack()
  entry2.date = "bingo"
  entry2.duration = 2.2

let entry3 = EntryPack()
  entry3.date = "dang"
  entry3.duration = 3.0

//Throw it all together into an array
var package = [entry1, entry2, entry3]

//Predicate for some filtering
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"date = %@", "bingo")
let results = (package as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate) as! [EntryPack]

//Sum all the parent object durations
let sum = results.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.duration }

print(sum) // = 3.3
```

But now I want to add up the `value` for each `CustomValuePack` where the `name` is `"Day"`.

I can't figure out how to do a similar reduce on a nested array of objects. I've tried something like this, but it yields a syntax error:

```
let sum2 = results.reduce(0.0) { $0.customValues + $1.customValues.value } //Error
```

**How do I sum the value in a nested array of objects?** I eventually want to apply an NSPredicate to filter by `name = Day` as well, but I'm not that far yet.

Comment: Why not apply a `flatMap` to flatten the arrays, then sum them? Currently, you're trying to take the sum of two *arrays*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `entries` defined as follow

```
let entries = [entry1, entry2, entry3]
```

you can extract the CustomValues with name == "Day" and sum the value field with this code

```
let sum = entries
    .flatMap { $0.customValues }
    .filter { $0.name == "Day" }
    .map { $0.value }
    .reduce(0, combine: +)
```

### Improvements

You are using Swift but for some reason there still is a lot of Objective-C into your code.

This is how i would refactor your code

```
struct EntryPack {
    let date: String
    let duration: Double
    let customValues:[CustomValuePack]
}

struct CustomValuePack {
    let name:String
    let value: Double
}

let cv1 = CustomValuePack(name: "Day", value: 1.2)
let cv2 = CustomValuePack(name: "Day", value: 1.3)
let cv3 = CustomValuePack(name: "Night", value: 2.2)

let entry1 = EntryPack(date: "bingo", duration: 1.1, customValues: [cv1, cv2])
let entry2 = EntryPack(date: "bingo", duration: 2.2, customValues: [])
let entry3 = EntryPack(date: "dang", duration: 3.0, customValues: [])
```

> Please note that now `EntryPack` and `CustomValuePack` are structs which are value types.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I'm working on understanding it. It appears the `.reduce` with the `combine` above is returning `1.2` when the right answer should be `2.5`.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum: Oh, let me check it

Comment: I have to dynamically create and combine the filters in my actual app which is why I'm using `NSPredicate`. As I understand it, my objects have to inherit from `NSObject` in order to use `NSPredicate`.

Comment: Never mind. The error was on my side. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CliftonLabrum: Ok fine.